# How to add a value to the queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I need to add a field 'All' to choices of ModelMultipleChoiceFilter. I don't know how to add custom value ('All') to queryset.

In MultipleChoiceFilter I just use:

```
shops = Shop.objects.filter(is_active=True)
SHOP_CHOICES = [('All', 'All')]
for x in shops:
    SHOP_CHOICES.append((x.address, x))
SHOP_CHOICES = tuple(SHOP_CHOICES)
```

but in ModelMultipleChoiceFilter I have queryset instead of tuple.

## My filter:

```
def departments(request):
    if request is None:
        return Shop.objects.none()

    curr_user = request.user
 
    return Shop.objects.filter(is_active=True, custom_user=curr_user)


class ShopFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    address = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=departments)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue using jquery and html

```
<script>
    $('#id_address').prepend(new Option('All', 'All'))
</script>
```